# Flixel. How to make a simple popup window in game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flixel

Hi I was looking all around for how to make a simple popup window in flixel but could not find any tutorials/help on how to do it. If anyone could give a simple example of it that would be great!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

1. Run the actual game-specific code in `update()` only if a bool is true.
2. If the popup "pops up" you set this bool to false.
3. Create a new Popup - FlxSprite.
4. If the user clicks the Popup - Sprite, you delete it and set the bool
   to true.